# Can't search array by indexOf()

Tags: javascript

I tried to put a series of DOM elements having the same class inside an array, and then try to find what index is one of them located by using .indexof(). However, it seems like it is not working. Did I wrote anything wrong? Or there should be other ways that I can find an index of an element in a array?

Here is a little piece of code

```
window.onload = function(){
    var addBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".add");
    for(var i = 0; i < addBtn.length; i++){
        addBtn[i].onclick = addTime;
    }
};

function addTime(){
    var update = parseInt(this.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")[0].innerHTML) + 1;
    var digits = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".digit");
    if(digits.indexOf(this.parentElement) % 2){ //Uncaught TypeError: digits.indexOf is not a function

    }else{
        carryOn(this, update);
    }
}
```

It just keep telling me that "Uncaught TypeError: digits.indexOf is not a function".

Comment: `indexOf` is a prototype of `array` not of `DOMElement Nodelist`

Comment: `[].slice.call(digits)` might help!

Comment: @RayonDabre Or [`Array.from(digits)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Ooh yes!

Comment: Or `[...digits]` (ES6)

Comment: .querySelectorAll('clsname'); will return a array of nodeList. That's why it is showing error.

Comment: @RayonDabre That really worked!!, so indexOf only work for normal arrays?

Comment: @Shubham thanks, now I know what's wrong

Comment: @RayonDabre you should submit it as an answer

Comment: @antoniskamamis, Provided answer looks good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` return a [**`NodeList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), it's an array-like object, not an actual array. It does not have an `indexOf` methods.

You can:

1. cast array method on an array-like by `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(digits, ....)`.
2. produce a real array by `Array.from(digits)`.